# Chrome create a custom chortcut application with own tab history

Tags: google-chrome

I want an ablility to create a custom chrome shortcut which would save open tabs. And after I close and open it again it would open last tabs. Currently I achieve this buy installing Chrome Canary. But I want a chrome on project with own tabs. I know that there is a possibility to create a shortcut to a certain website but that is not what I want.